# Mac mini: Mouse left click not working

Tags: mac, mouse, mac-mini, mouse-keys

Today the left click of the mouse connected to my Mac mini is not working. I tried to change mouse and I tried the mouse on a different Mac, and it works. The problem still persists on my Mac mini.

Can this be a hardware problem? How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you go to System Preferences → Mouse and see if Primary Mouse button is correctly set?

Comment: This is what I was thinking